# VBA code is not working as it should work smoothly

Tags: excel, vba

Using this code it takes almost 30 seconds to complete work on 100 rows and 150 column my data is increasing swiftly and soon code will take more time to initiate. please guide me what is wrong with this code.

```
Sub Colourise()
Dim r As Long, Val As String, C As Long
Worksheets("Assets").Activate
r = 1
Val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 43).Value
C = 6 '6 is yellow, 8 is cyan
For r = 1 To ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 43).Value) Then ' column 43 is client name
Exit For
End If
If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 43).Value <> Val Then
If C = 8 Then
C = 6
Else
C = 8
End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 80)).Select ' column 80 is end of data
With Selection.Interior
.ColorIndex = C
.Pattern = xlSolid
End With
Val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 43).Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all don't use `ActiveSheet`, `Selection`, `Select` and stuff like that. Be more specific.

Comment: Then what i should use rather than ActiveSheet, Selection, Select

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Also You can implement 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' at the beginning and set this to 'True' in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are using `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`, which is probably 2^20 rows (unless you have a very old version). The amount of data will not affect how long this takes to run, since you are looking at every row, empty or otherwise. It will always scan about 1M rows.

As well as referring to the specific sheet by name, you should use UsedRange instead.

i.e.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Your sheet")

For r = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
...
```

Comment: Glad to. You might want to consider using conditional formatting instead of VBA for this task.

Comment: can you please edit the code i have tried but its not working.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Is there an error somewhere? What does the entire new function look like (edit your post).

Comment: Sub Colourise()
Dim r As Long, Val As String, C As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Assets")
r = 1
Val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 43).Value
C = 6 '6 is yellow, 8 is cyan
For r = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, 43).Value) Then ' column 43 is client name
Exit For
End If
If ws.Cells(r, 43).Value <> Val Then
If C = 8 Then
C = 6
Else
C = 8
End If
End If
ws.Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 80)).Select ' column 80 is end of data
With Selection.Interior
.ColorIndex = C
.Pattern = xlSolid
End With
Val = ws.Cells(r, 43).Value
Next
End Sub

Comment: You are missing an `If` before `IsEmpty`